# How do I do select where year is provided as parameter of function

Tags: sql, date, plsql

Im trying to set up a certain procedure where i need to set up a function including cursor.

I have everything done and it's working besides select checking if the cursor's record are during a year that is provided as a function's argument (something like function(id,year)...)
But i do not know how to write it down in sql. I've tried using between year-01-01 and year-12-31, it seems only work if i enter things like "2016-01-01" and so on.  Is there a way to do it in simple way?

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully and provide us with your current code or code example.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: In Oracle, assuming you pass the year as an `integer` parameter named `p_year`, then `trunc(to_date(p_year,'YYYY'),'YEAR')` is January 1st, and `trunc(to_date(p_year +1,'YYYY'),'YEAR') -1` is December 31st. You could use those expressions directly in your query, or save them into variables for a more readable query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 
select my_filed where year(field_date) = year(given_date)

I think this is ANSI
select my_field where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)

Not sure but SQL server also has implementation for YEAR(date_field)

Comment: I failed to say im using PLSQL, but EXTRACT method worked perfeclty as i wanted. Thanks for help!

Comment: ANSI is a safe bet. It is the basic implementation of SQL in all SQL implementations. (it is not always the fastest tho).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function year, if you use sql server
example

```
declare @d as date
set @d='01/05/2019'
select year(@d) [year]
```

Comment: How do you know Mateusz is using SQL Server?